# I missed data from my system but i uploaded that on parse how can i recover it?

Tags: parse-platform, missing-data

I loaded a game on parse one year ago, By some mistake i deleted that application from my system but that's uploaded on parse, I don't know how i can find that data from parse Please suggest me How data can recovered?

Comment: do you want to get the ios code back? because that's not possible to get from parse

Comment: Thanks for help, so from where i got that code?

Answer (score 0):

If you've deleted the code and you don't have it on git, you're out of luck.